# Mysql connecting to iseries

Tags: database, odbc

Any easy way to get mysql server to query from an iseries (as/400 db2)? I have the odbc installed so I can query and export the data manually to my desktop and then import it to mysql.

The problem is the as400 database is so huge the performance is poor. I need to run a query every 1/2 hour or so on mysql to pull the new updated information on the iseries database.

Basically how do you use odbc on the mysql server to query from the iseries odbc?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked on an iSeries for over 10 years but - here is what I know/remember.
You create physical files and then logicals(sort sequences) over them.
To help make it as efficient as possible the FIRST logical that will be executed during a "reorg" should contain ALL the fields you will use in any subsequent select/sequence logicals. Then the following logicals will use the first logical to built themselves - it is now ONLY using an index instead of a physical file.
Second when you use open query it looks for a logical that is "pre-built". If it can't find one at least "near" what it needs it has to build one of its own every time.
My next point is the file you are reading and selecting from. When a record is added does it update physical/logicals immediately? On open? On close?
If you are looking for speed for your query then you don't want to be busy updating the records which have been added.
Note that if these are order entry type of records the update may be deliberately delayed to enhance the data entry process.
Hope this helps - An "updated" and "appropriate" keyed and sequenced logical will make a huge difference.
If you don't know the iSeries you need someone who does that can check that side. Cheers Ted

Answer (score 0):

Data replication.  One method is using a row update timestamp and using column to drive the replication.

```
alter table mylib.mytable add column
UPDATETS TIMESTAMP GENERATED ALWAYS FOR EACH ROW   
  ON UPDATE AS ROW CHANGE TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
```

Now your replication would use the updatets column and pull rows with a updatets greater than the current max(updatets) in the mysql database.